# rendering existing categories in view, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, view

How do I render a list of existing categories in my views?

My categories table has a `:name` column.

products view

```
 = f.select :category_name, Category.all.map{|s| [s.name]}
```

Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categoricals
    validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, presence: true
    acts_as_tree order: "name"
end
```

Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   include ActionView::Helpers
   include Categorizable
end
```

UPDATE:

Full product form

```
= simple_form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
        = f.input :title, placeholder: "Product Name", required: false, label: false
        = f.input :description, placeholder: "Description", required: false, label: false
        = f.select :category_name, Category.all.map{|s| s.name}

        = f.input :image, label: false


    = f.button :submit, class: "button"
```

UPDATE #2: 
products controller

```
def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
        redirect_to @product, notice: "Your Product was successfully updated!"
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

categorical model

```
class Categorical < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :categorizable, polymorphic: true

validates_presence_of :category, :categorizable
end
```

categorizable module

```
    module Categorizable 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :categoricals, as: :categorizable
    has_many :categories, through: :categoricals
  end

  def add_to_category(category)
    self.categoricals.create(category: category)
  end

  def remove_from_category(category)
    self.categoricals.find_by(category: category).maybe.destroy
  end


 module ClassMethods
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never understand why people don't use [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) over `select`:

```
= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name
```

---

It seems the real problem is due to your relations:

```
#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end

#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category #-> requires category_id column in products table
end
```

This will allow you to reference the `:category_id` as follows:

```
= simple_form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |f|
    = f.input :title, placeholder: "Product Name", required: false, label: false
    = f.input :description, placeholder: "Description", required: false, label: false
    = f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name
    = f.input :image, label: false

    = f.button :submit, class: "button"
```

Comment: I also prefer `collection_select` over `select`!

Comment: OK. one issue, it lists all the categories which is great but when I choose the relevant one it doesn't update the product attributes.

Comment: When you say "doesn't update the product attributes", do you mean the params which are passed to the controller, or the ones sent to the database?

Comment: Okay. So for some reason, when I created a 'category_name' column in my products table it retrieves the category id number and not the name! I really think it has something to do with the categorizable module. If you have an alternate category model in mind please let me know...thanks!

Comment: Which table are you putting `category_name` into? If it's `Category`, it should just be `name`, right?

Comment: Right, in the categories table there's a 'name' column, and the products table has a corresponding 'category_name' column.

Comment: Why `category_name`? Is there a specific reason why you wouldn't use `category_id`?

Comment: yes. since i'd like to retrieve the category name in my products view by calling = @product.category_name. The weird thing is that by doing this now I get the ID (by calling category_name). What do you think about my category model in general? would you change it?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be `category_id`

Comment: How would you retrieve the category name then?

Comment: For what purpose? If it's to populate a select box as described above, I would use the code I wrote. If you want to call it from an action, you'd be able to use `@product.categories.find(x).name`

Comment: What I currently use is - @product.categories.each do |category|  = link_to(category.name, category) but then when I use the code you offered for populating the select box it doesn't update the changes in the view page.

Comment: Do you have a repo I could look at?

Comment: i've posted the entire category model, have you looked it it?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
= f.select :category_name, Category.all.map{|s| s.name}
```

In order to make this work, you have to have `category_name` column present in your `products` table.

Comment: I get 'undefined method `category_name'' How do I let rails know :name is in the categories table?

Comment: can you show the full form code in your products view?

Comment: does your `products` table have a `category_name` column in it?

Comment: Nope. Just added category_id as was suggested.

Comment: That's why you got that error. Anyways, Rich Peck's answer shows the better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Yup, thanks so much though. Also, do you happen to know how to solve the issue I mentioned above? "OK. one issue, it lists all the categories which is great but when I choose the relevant one it doesn't update the product attributes."

Comment: Are you saving the product after selecting the category? But, still its not updating the record in the database?

Comment: In that case, please show your `products`'s `update` method.

Comment: Sure. Let me also post my entire category model since I think it has something to do with this.

Comment: Show your `product_params` method. You may need to add `:category_id` in the list.

Comment: I added category_id to the params list as well. I think it has to do with my Categorizable module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93298/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-liroy).